# How to test react-router-dom views with data loader?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I have a React application with react-router-dom set up like this:

`App.tsx:`

```
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'

import router from 'app/router'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
)
```

`app/router:`

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import DataComponent from 'app/views/data'

export const routes = [{
  path: '/data',
  element: (
    <DataComponent />
  ),
  loader: async () => {
    const { data, error } = await api.getData()
    if (error) {
      store.dispatch(message({ type: 'error', text: error.message }))
    } else {
      store.dispatch(setData(data))
    }
    return null
  },
}]

export default createBrowserRouter(routes)
```

data.test.tsx:

```
import { routes } from 'app/router'

describe('views/data', () => {
  it('should render component', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <DataComponent />,
      {
        wrapper: () => (
          <RouterProvider
            router={createMemoryRouter(routes, {
              initialEntries: ['/data'],
            })}
          />
        )
      }
    })
    expect(...)
  })
})
```

Now when I run jest I get empty div on render. I do successfully mock loader function, api response, of course, – mocking works, but rendering does not, only empty div. But when I remove data loader from route's options and mock a data store, jest finally renders my view. So I suspect rtl renders the view before async loader function returns. Is there a way to hold the rendering until loader returns? Do memory and browser router treat loader functions the same way? May be you have an experience testing `react-router-dom` apps with loaders?

UPDATE:
I called the render function in a wrong way. Of course, `element` to render should be `<RouterProvider />`, wrapper includes theme and storage context providers:

```
describe('views/data', () => {
  it('should render component', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <RouterProvider
        router={createMemoryRouter(routes, {
          initialEntries: ['/data'],
        })}
      />
    })
    expect(...)
  })
})
```

The context providers mentioned above have nothing to do with my problem, because tests work flawlessly on other components, where loader function is missing on respective route configuration

Comment: Where does the `store` come from?

Comment: @LinDu, There is one more context provider: `<ReduxProvider store={store}>`. I tried to remove every distraction from the code. I am sure the store has nothing to do with the issue – I removed from loader function all interactions with the store and still get the empty `div`. I think I need some trick for rendering, like `act()` or `waitFor()` for component state update

Comment: if it helps someone, RTL rendered the component, when I removed `Router` from `Providers`. I think it means that when I add `RouterProvider` RTL renders not the element I am passing to render function, but one that is matching the route I pass to a RouterProvider. So I may remove the `RouterProvider`, but will it be a proper unit testing? Yes, the component is being tested in isolation, mocked contex matches the one provided in app. But it is strange to me that Router created with `createMemoryRouter` fails on loader function

Comment: `createMemoryRouter()` should be called with `{ waitForData: true }` option.

`describe('views/data', () => {
  it('should render component', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <RouterProvider
        router={createMemoryRouter(routes, {
          initialEntries: ['/data'],
          waitForData: true
        })}
      />
    })
    expect(...)
  })
})`
With this option jest waits for loader to finish and renders component after that.

Comment: Thank you @Talha for the input. Unfortunately typescript is unaware of the option. The thread started from `react-router-dom` v6.6.x, ATM working with the latest v7 – no such option. Even if it was with these versions, I tried to `@ts-ignore` the missing option error and include it – no luck. But I fixed my issue. I should closely follow the example [provided by authors](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-memory-router). I probably misused `waitFor`. Now when I properly wrap `await waitFor` around lookup function my tests properly render the component

Comment: Oops, v6.7 of course, not v7 :)

Comment: I'm struggling with this myself.  But the reason that you are getting an empty div is that the `wrapper` needs to render its `children`.  A typical wrapper would be something like `wrapper: ({ children }) => <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>`.